# visual-line-mode adaptively wrapping when changing font size

Tags: eww, visual-line-mode

`visual-line-mode` works fine for line wrapping in `eww-mode`. However, when I type <kbd>C-x C-+</kbd> / <kbd>C-x C--</kbd> to change the font size, the line wrapping does not adjust accordingly.

Does anyone know how can this be achieved?

Comment: `eww` won't reflow the document unless you reload it. If you want your font size changing commands to reflow the document, you'd need to advise them with a function that runs `eww-reload` afterwards (which has an optional argument to use a local copy rather than fetching the document again).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @DoMiNeLa10's advice. I tried to add a local hook for `text-scale-mode`, it does work.

```el
(defun my/text-scale-mode-hook ()
  (eww-reload :local))

(add-hook 'eww-mode-hook
          (lambda()
            (add-hook 'text-scale-mode-hook
                      'my/text-scale-mode-hook
                      nil :local)))
```